# Ubuntu has invalid checksum in blocks ~once a week

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I use Ubuntu 18.04 on my server machine. **Once a week** Ubuntu has invalid checksum for blocks, so Ubuntu enters read only mode, after which processes fails and Ubuntu restart is needed. During booting journal shows invalid checksum recovering block, and after I execute fsck command it gets back up. This is totally breaking for me, because website is not working until I get involved and manually do st.. Relevant stack that I use: mongod for database, pyton with forking multiprocesses for webscraping.

This bug happans around python webscraping job running, either some little delta time before it finishes or immidiatly after. Mongod logs shows some connection ending, and than it restarts on it's own and fails to get port 27017, because it needs to change some file so it fails.
This connections ending sometimes seems good:

```
2020-07-09T05:08:29.477+0200 I NETWORK  [conn399] end connection 127.0.0.1:46798 (10 connections now open)
2020-07-09T05:08:29.477+0200 I NETWORK  [conn398] end connection 127.0.0.1:46796 (9 connections now open)
2020-07-09T05:53:36.207+0200 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2020-07-09T05:53:36.244+0200 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledPr$
2020-07-09T05:53:36.380+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=963 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit ho$
2020-07-09T05:53:36.380+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.10
```

And sometimes not ( notice ^@ characteres)

```
2020-07-04T22:42:57.252+0200 I NETWORK  [conn602] end connection 127.0.0.1:39808 (14 connections now open)
2020-07-04T22:42:57.252+0200 I NETWORK  [conn601] end connection 127.0.0.1:398^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^$
2020-07-05T00:53:30.611+0200 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-07-05T00:53:30.703+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=930 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=mojtiketServerComputerName
2020-07-05T00:53:30.703+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.10
```

Another possible culprit (although less likely) is that python spawn new processes with fork method where each has it's own file to write errors that happened.

Once I run fsck in terminal while ubuntu was in read_only mode without restarting os, mongod couldn't recover and had to reinstall it. I already reported this bug to mongodb team. The lines below are from this  execution.

Can you help me by telling me how to triage this, how to mitigate this etc.

```
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering block 95420432 in log
JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering block 46 in log
JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering block 95420455 in log
JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering block 95420456 in log
JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering block 95945036 in log
JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering block 95420432 in log

myUserName@myComputerName:~$ sudo fsck -f /
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 23855152, end of extent exceeds allowed value
        (logical block 83, physical block 95588851, len 5)
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 23855152, i_blocks is 688, should be 672.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23855358, i_blocks is 1968, should be 1960.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23855668, i_blocks is 5712, should be 5704.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23865002, end of extent exceeds allowed value
        (logical block 6, physical block 47764987, len 3)
Clear<y>? yes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 29097997 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Deleted inode 29098009 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry 'job.cache.N' in /var/cache/cups (23855431) has deleted/unused inode 23855386.  Clear<y>? yes
Entry 'metrics.interim' in /var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data (23865008) has deleted/unused inode 23855125.  Clear<y>? yes
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Unconnected directory inode 13238821 (/home/mtp/project/prod/webscraper/Logging/???)
Connect to /lost+found ('a' enables 'yes' to all) <y>? yes to all
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Inode 12191776 ref count is 1305, should be 1306.  Fix? yes

Unattached inode 13238738
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Inode 13238738 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Unattached inode 13238755
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Inode 13238755 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Unattached inode 13238788
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Inode 13238788 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Unattached inode 13238812
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Inode 13238812 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Inode 13238821 ref count is 5, should be 4.  Fix? yes

Unattached inode 13238825
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Inode 13238825 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Unattached inode 13238826
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Inode 13238826 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Unattached inode 13238827
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Inode 13238827 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Unattached inode 13238828
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Inode 13238828 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Unattached inode 23855247
Connect to /lost+found? yes

Inode 23855247 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes

Inode 23855279 ref count is 1, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Inode 23855334 ref count is 1, should be 2.  Fix? yes

Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -2060872 +(47755985--47755986) +(47755992--47756020) +47756082 -47756083 -47764445 -(47765295--47765296) -(47765515--47765528) -(47765575--47765589) +(52961514--52961515) -(52986152--52986154) +(75544092--75544097) -(95453700--95453703) -(95588851--95588855) -(95621149--95621161) +(95651808--95651825) +(95662080--95663552) -(95664128--95665599) -(95666112--95666143) -95713396 +(95775716--95775718)
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #43 (17234, counted=17235).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #1457 (31366, counted=31367).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #1617 (32410, counted=32413).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #2305 (29062, counted=29056).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #2913 (14362, counted=14366).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #2917 (15501, counted=15506).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #2918 (11211, counted=11224).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #2920 (6686, counted=6687).
Fix? yes

Free blocks count wrong (112183187, counted=112183209).
Fix? yes

Inode bitmap differences:  +1312455 -1312466 -23855125 +23855247 -23855386 -29097997 -29098009
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #160 (5233, counted=5234).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #2912 (1772, counted=1774).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong for group #3552 (8162, counted=8164).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong (29020534, counted=29020538).
Fix? yes


/dev/sda2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda2: ***** REBOOT SYSTEM *****
/dev/sda2: 257670/29278208 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 4898135/117081344 blocks
```

Multiple runs of smartctl ended without error:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.3.0-53-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     KINGSTON SA400S37480G
Serial Number:    50026B7682672C22
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 682672c22
Firmware Version: SBFKB1C2
User Capacity:    480,103,981,056 bytes [480 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jul 10 05:29:42 2020 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (65535) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  30) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   000   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1163
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25
148 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
149 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       14
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       10
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       131087
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       14
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   069   066   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 22/34)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
218 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0000   001   001   000    Old_age   Offline      -       99
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       586
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       108
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
244 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2
245 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       15
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       38240
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       38240

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1050         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1043         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1042         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Comment: The most common cause of that is a failing/failed hard disk. Run `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` and post the output here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton **I Updated the answer**. Comment: I already run that and no error were found. I read that most likely hard disk is the problem, but in my case I have a brand new ssd and the report is fine:

Comment: Hm, your SMART data looks fine, so I expect something else is corrupting your filesystem. Likely some software running as root that is misconfigured to write to the raw device for some reason. What that could be, I have no way to know, but you as the admin should be able to make some educated guesses.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, to be honost I have no clue which process would do that. I set-up server machine for my website only. The command "sudo fatrace -t | grep "/var/lib/mongodb" >> /tmp/iolog_mongodb1 &" should print which processes changed files in directory reserved for mongodb data.  I guess we will see weather this will show process_id that causess problems, next time it happens. Do you have some better solution/advice?